# Highlight rows that don't match other sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, conditional-formatting

I'm not sure if this is possible, but I have two spreadsheets that I need to compare in a few different ways.

Here is the scenario:

```
**Sheet 1** 
Column O=Claim Number;
Column P=Reserve Indemnity; 
Column Q=Reserve Expense.  


**Sheet 2** 
Column J=Associated Matter ID;
Column K=Reserve Indemnity;
Column L=Defense Reserve.
```

I need the followings things to occur:

1. Look for matches between sheet 1 col O and sheet 2 col J and highlight any rows on either sheet that don't have a corresponding match on the opposite sheet.
2. Once it finds a match in 1 above I need it to see if sheet 1 col P and sheet 2 col K also match and highlight it if they do not.
3. Once it finds a match in 1 above I need it to see if sheet 1 col Q and sheet 2 col L also match and highlight it if they do not.

I am spending hours comparing these two spreadsheets each month looking for discrepancies, and I don't have time for it.  I'm sure there is an easier way, but I do not know enough about Excel to figure it out myself.  Can anyone help me?

Comment: "Can anyone help me?" is not a valid question here. Of course someone can help, but Super User is not a script or formula writing service. There is a reasonable expectation that you will attempt to resolve this first, then give details of what you have tried and ask a specific question about where you get stuck.  You can read ***[ask]*** if you need help improving your question.

Answer (score 0):

Are the values in these columns numeric?  A really simple comparison is to just subtract one value from the other.  If the answer is not zero, they do not match.  Then you can scroll down an look for non-zero numbers, or make the conditional formatting change the cell color if the difference is greater then 0.

Comment: Yes they are numeric.  I think your idea would work but I am not sure how to account for the fact that either sheet could have claim numbers that don't appear on the opposite sheet.  Even if I sorted them by claim number if there is an extra number on one sheet it would throw off the rows and presumably mess up the formula because you would end up comparing claim numbers that dont match..

Comment: You are correct that a minor change to the rows in one sheet would create a big problem to your calculations.  The problem here is you are using your Excel Spreadsheet as a database.  Excel is not a database, but is really just an advanced calculator.  That being said, many great databases start out as ideas in a spreadsheet.  Maybe it is time to upgrade to a database.  I know that is not the answer you are looking for.  Getting back to the original question, if your rows get out of sync, the method of subtracting one value from another will make it obvious where the problem begins.